# If a transformer's thermal fuse is blown, would it show Open Circuit?

Tags: transformer

If a transformer's thermal fuse is blown, would it show Open Circuit? (that's what I would expect)

I.e if you have a transformer, that is showing continuity and expected valid resistance on the primary coil, does that mean you can be 100% sure that the thermal fuse is intact?

(Trying to diagnose a transformer that passes all multimeter tests for continuity/resistance, but produces no output voltage)

Comment: Your fuse is definitely intact. You can not know if it is damaged with a multimeter, but if the transformer does not produce output voltage the fault is elsewhere. Did you check the secondary resistance?

Comment: Yes resistance on all coils seems fine. No continuity between coils. Transformer from a stereo amplifier. Primary has 110v AC in. There are three thick wires that service manual states should be 250v, but no voltage is seen.

Comment: When taken out and tested on the bench, turns out transformer is fine.  When the transformer is installed, something else cuts power to the transformer upon startup.

Comment: Are you sure there is a thermal fuse **in** the transformer?

Comment: No. Just understood it was common on stereo amplifiers. @Vladimir You answered the question, but I am unable to accept a comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thermal fuse is designed to fail open. If it would fail short I would rather call it thermal detonator, or something like that.

Your fuse is definitely intact. You can not know if it has been damaged with just a multimeter, but if the transformer does not produce output voltage the fault is elsewhere.

Try to check the secondary winding or other support circuits that might be connected to the transformer.